# Как получить value выбранного option для последующей вставки в функцию на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript, select, value

Есть `select` на 12 месяцев

```
  <select name="select" id="selectMonth" class="select">
        <option value=1>январь</option>
        <option value=2>февраль</option>
        <option value=3>март</option>
```

И есть функция, которая выводит массив данных "день месяца-день недели"

```
let getDaysArray = (year, month) => {
 let monthIndex = month - 1;
 let names = Object.freeze(["пн", "вт", "ср", "чт", "пт", "сб", "вс"]);
let date = new Date(year, monthIndex, 1);`
  let result = [];
  while (date.getMonth() == monthIndex) {
    result.push(`${date.getDate()} ${names[date.getDay()]}`);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      }
  return result;
}
```

Я хочу, чтобы в эту функцию месяц подставлялся по значению выбранного value из списка месяцев.

let d = getDaysArray(2020, );

Если я ставлю значение вручную, например, `let d = getDaysArray(2020, 3);` 
то все получается. Но я-то хочу автоматом.
Если  добавить так

```
let chosenMonth = document.querySelector("select");
let d = getDaysArray(2020, chosenMonth.options[chosenMonth.selectedIndex].value)
```

то получается, но только для первого `option`, который загружается. Другие месяцы уже не выводятся. 
Пыталась через `document.querySelector('.select').onchange = e => console.log(e.target.value);` получить значение. Но номер `value` выводится только в консоль, а для подстановки в функцию я не понимаю как его получить.

Нужно получить этот массив не в консоль, а для дальнейшего использования в таком виде

document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML= d[0];

Comment: добавьте HTML, так быстрее можно понять суть вопроса

Answer (score 1):

так?

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');

select.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const x = getDaysArray(2020, +e.target.value);
  
  console.log(x);
});

let getDaysArray = (year, month) => {
  let monthIndex = month - 1;
  let names = Object.freeze(["пн", "вт", "ср", "чт", "пт", "сб", "вс"]);
  let date = new Date(year, monthIndex, 1);
  let result = [];
  while (date.getMonth() == monthIndex) {
    result.push(`${date.getDate()} ${names[date.getDay()]}`);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return result;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">Январь</option>
  <option value="2">Февраль</option>
  <option value="3">Март</option>
</select>
```

Comment: спасибо! я немного дополнила в конце свой вопрос. Как получить этот массив для дальнейшего использования?

Comment: @user385671, запись его в переменную

Comment: А как? У меня не получается. С выводом в консоль работает и мой вариант document.querySelector('.select').onchange = e => console.log(e.target.value); Но присвоить значение почему-то не выходит((

Comment: Вот, например, для option по умолчанию (только январь) получается присвоить переменную: let d = getDaysArray(2020, chosenMonth.options[chosenMonth.selectedIndex].value)   А сделать так же с вашим вариантом (убрав console.log) у меня не выходит.

Comment: @user385671, обновил